# Can elastic collisions happen at a distance via gravity?

Tags: gravity, momentum, collision

We all know about elastic collisions in Newtonian physics where real-world sized object collide with each other, but is it possible for objects to exchange momentum in a similar way through gravity without actually touching?

Comment: The gravitational force of the Sun on the Earth is constantly changing the Earth’s momentum, and vice versa. Without them touching!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all gravitational interactions do this (elastically).

Comment: I suspect so, but can you back it up with some kind of formula or equation?

Comment: @DerekSeabrooke are you serious? F = mg, $\Delta p = F \Delta t$. You might just be overthinking things

Comment: Me overthink something?  Never!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [gravity assist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_assist). In this process, an object like e.g. a spaceship is carefully directed so as to fly at a particular angle and velocity very close to a massive object like a planet. These two objects don't touch, but the gravitational interaction makes them exchange momentum, in particular, changes velocity of the spaceship by a large amount, saving fuel.

Example of a real-life mission: Voyager 2 (animation [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Animation_of_Voyager_2_trajectory.gif)):

[image]